# flatten numpy arrays lists of lists to 4 values per line

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, for-loop

I have created an array that has 4 values per line

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as itertools
import timeit
aL = np.random.randint(0,100,size=750000) # 10 random ints
bL = np.random.randint(0,100,size=750000) # 10 random ints


xL = np.arange(1000)
yL = np.arange(750)

lenx = len(xL) # 5
leny = len(yL) # 2

arr = np.ndarray(shape=(leny, lenx, 4)) # create a 3-d array

for x in range(leny):
    arr[x,:,0] = xL


for y in range(lenx):
    arr[:,y,1] = yL

a_reshaped = aL.reshape(leny,lenx)
b_reshaped = bL.reshape(leny,lenx)

arr[:,:,2] = a_reshaped
arr[:,:,3] = b_reshaped

print(arr)
```

My output now looks like this:

```
[[[  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   4.00000000e+01   2.30000000e+01]
  [  1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   8.50000000e+01   1.40000000e+01]
  [  2.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   7.20000000e+01   2.00000000e+00]
  ..., 
  [  1.44600000e+03   0.00000000e+00   9.20000000e+01   4.60000000e+01]
  [  1.44700000e+03   0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+01   6.10000000e+01]
  [  1.44800000e+03   0.00000000e+00   8.40000000e+01   9.40000000e+01]]]
```

I want to output each 4 values per one line. For example

1    0    2.5    3.5

I have tried this:

```
np.fromiter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(arr), dtype='int')
```

But it didn't do the trick for me.

The result I am looking for is something like this:

```
1   1   0.1   11
1   2   0.2   12
1   3   0.3   13
1   4   0.4   14
.....
1000   745   0.986   86
1000   746   0.987   97
1000   747   0.989   98
1000   748   0.990   99
1000   749   0.991   100
1000   750   0.992   110
```

EDIT

Say I have a list of 5 x points and 3 y points, and 2 random numbers at each x,y  pair. I want that each x values pairs with every y value and vice versa. This means I will get 15 lines of output. The problem is I have a list of 1449 x values and 638 values to get the job done and iterate over every single on it takes hours.

Someone provided me with the code above to do such job faster and it does. Now I get and array with lists of lists. I want to flatten those to get something similar to this:

```
0.   0.    8.  12.
1.   0.   17.   8.
2.   0.    1.  18.
3.   0.   17.  12.
4.   0.    3.  12.
0.   1.    6.  13.
1.   1.   16.  14.
2.   1.    8.   0.
3.   1.   12.   8.
4.   1.    2.  12.
0.   2.    4.   8.
1.   2.    2.   3.
2.   2.    4.   3.
3.   2.    2.   3.
4.   2.   13.  13.
```

I hope this clarifies it more.

EDIT 2

My output now looks like this:

```
[[  0   0  48  69]
 [  0   1  37  12]
 [  0   2  15  30]
 ..., 
 [749 997  64  14]
 [749 998  61   7]
 [749 999   1  74]]
```

Is it possible to switch the first 2 rows such that the above becomes this:

```
[[  0   0  48  69]
 [  1   0  37  12]
 [  2   0  15  30]
 ..., 
 [997 749  64  14]
 [998 749  61   7]
 [999 749   1  74]]
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Use a minimal/small input and show us the expected output?

Comment: @Divakar I have updated the main post, hope this helps more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that with numpy reshaping and broadcasting

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as itertools
import timeit
aL = np.random.randint(0,100,size=750000) # 10 random ints
bL = np.random.randint(0,100,size=750000) # 10 random ints


xL = np.arange(1000)
yL = np.arange(750)


yL, xL = np.ix_(yL, xL) # this prepares x and y for broadcasting such
                        # that all possible combinations are generated

out = np.empty((750,1000,4), dtype=int)

out[..., 0] = yL  # y is 750x1
out[..., 1] = xL  # x is 1x1000
out.shape = -1, 4 # this flattens the array to shape 750,000x4
out[..., 2] = aL  # so a
out[..., 3] = bL  # and b can be inserted

print(out)
```

To swap columns (be sure not to miss the `.copy`):

```
out[..., 1], out[...., 0] = out[..., 0], out[..., 1].copy()
```

To print every single line you could try something like

```
print('\n'.join([(2*"{: 8.0f}" + 2*"{: 12.04f}").format(*l) for l in out]))
```

Comment: this is doing the same as the output I gave in the main post. I really need every line and not the first 2 lines then a couple dots and then the last two lines.

Comment: @AhmedAli you mean the problem is the actual printing out? Then try something like `np.set_printoptions(threshold=10**10)` The function has more options conrolling the printing of arrays.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. Unfortunately, this line np.set_printoptions(threshold=10**10) didnt do the trick for me. I tried it with a for loop but then I am back at square one and it just takes for ever

Comment: @AhmedAli I've added a line to the answer which takes a few seconds to execute. But what do you want with the output? You can't print it, you can't read it, you'll have difficulties to merely scroll through it...

Comment: can I format each values of the 4 such that the first 2 are ints and the last 2 are dec

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I have one last question. Could you take a look at my 2nd edit? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if I would get the same result if I switch these two lines out[..., 0] = yL and out[..., 1] = xL to become out[..., 0] = xL and out[..., 1] = yL?

Comment: @AhmedAli Well yes, obviously that works just as well.